# Test TCP/UDP client for windows ce

Tags: sockets, client, windows-ce, opennetcf, mobile-devices

On Windows desktop I use [SocketTest](http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/) as GUI tool to test TCP connections.

Is there alternative for Windows CE (native are preferred) to test connections with Windows Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Winsock API (winsock 2.x at least) on Windows CE is quite similar to the one you've on "full" Windows. If those samples are not using too many advanced UI features porting them to CE won't be too complex. If the GUI part is not easy to convert you can still keep the low-level socked-related routines.

Comment: OK, I can use http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14585/CCESocket-a-general-purpose-TCP-UDP-socket-class-f